# Talking to a Ruby class’ instance of another class

Tags: ruby, class, instance

This has probably been answered before, but I lack the proper vocabulary to find the solution using the board search.

What I want to achieve is to calling methods of a class’ instance of another class.

I think this crude example illustrates what I want to achieve:

```
class ClassA
  def method_a
    return 'first example'
  end

  def method_b
    return 'second example'
  end
end

class ClassB
  def initialize
    object = classA.new
  end
end

the_example = classB.new
the_example.[whatever-I’m-missing-to-talk-with-object].method_b 
# should return 'second exampe'
```

Comment: Your code sample wouldn't run, because `classA` starts with a lowercase letter. You may want to run code in IRB before posting it on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`object` needs to be an instance variable so that it doesn't go out of scope after the call to `initialize`, so call it `@object` instead.

Then you'll need to make `@object` accessible outside of `classB`'s definition, so you'll want to declare that.

```
class ClassB
  attr_reader :object # lets you call 'some_instance_of_classb.object'
  def initialize
    @object = ClassA.new
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Rather than exposing the `@object` variable, you can use a delegator:

```
require "forwardable"

class ClassB
  extend Forwardable
  def_delegators :@object, :method_b

  def initialize
    @object = ClassA.new
  end
end
```

that way, when `the_example` receives a `method_b` call, it knows to delegate it, by returning the result of `@object.method_b`.